# How set pop up to right bottom in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to set pop up to right bottom of window of window . i found code to set pop up to center of window .

```
$(id).css('top',  winH/2-$(id).height()/2);
$(id).css('left', winW/2-$(id).width()/2);
```

Comment: `$(id).css({'bottom': 0, 'right': 0});`

Comment: it is taking pop up to top left portion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
$(id).css({'position':'fixed', 'bottom': 0, 'right': 0 });
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/863vx6w4/)